# Android - Error testing a toast

Tags: android, mockito

I made a test with `mockito` that `verifies` if a Toast was called.
When I run only my class test, IT WORKS.

```
Toast toast = mock(Toast.class);
verify(toast, times(1)).makeText(Robolectric.application, R.string.no_internet_connection, 1).show();
```

But when I run all my tests, it shows an error. I don't understand why.
When I remove that line, and run the tests, Log doesn't show me any error.

Console:

```
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at co.m.....(TestNetworkUtil.java:131)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at co.m...
```

Comment: When you remove the line you basically remove your test.

Comment: Exactly, but when I test just that java class, the test works.

Comment: Have you using any network call(in TestNetworkUtil.java), as using mockito(with roboelectrict) , actual  Http call is not possible.We need to mock that method instead of calling actual one.

Comment: I already mock that method. I don't understand why, when I run the test just for that java file, the test are OK. But, if I run all the test java files it shows an error.

Comment: I debug the test and it arrives to the toast and works. How is it possible that when I run all the test together it just doesn't work